# Bound mismatch: The type class name is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends interfacename> of the type Service<T>

Tags: java, web-services, generics, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have an interface below:

```
interface Find {
  List<String> getParams();
}
```

I have a simple POJO class as below:

```
public class FindSystem<T extends Find> {
  private List<String> params;
  private Class<T> clazz;
  public List<String> setParams(List<String> params) {
    ...
  }
  public List<String> getParams() {
    ...
  }

  public Class<T> getClazz() {
     return clazz;
  }

  public find setClazz(Class<T> clazz) {
     this.clazz = clazz;
     return this;
  }
}
```

I have a service class as:

```
 public class FindService<T extends Find> {

    public fetch(Class<T> class) {
      FindSystem<T> f = new FindSystem<T>();
      f.setClazz(clazz);
      Find en = f.getClazz().newInstance();
      f.setParams(en.getParams());
    }
 }
```

I have a Controller class, where System is an entity class mapping to a table in database:

```
@Path("/find")
public class FindController {

@Inject
FindService<System> systemservice; //Getting error here Bound Mismatch, the type System is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Find> of the type FindService<T>
...
}
```

Getting error at:

`FindService<System> systemservice;` // Bound Mismatch, the type System is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type FindService

Comment: What is `System`? Very important information...`System` must implement `find`. (edit: and actually `findService systemservice<System>;` is a straight-up syntax error so I don't understand the question now. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: System is implementing interface find in findService class....

Comment: Just a suggestion: Class and interface names Must start with Uppercase letter. This makes it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: @NarendraPathai ok..thanks, will take that into consideration

Comment: @RC. I was consumed with formatting I forgot to validate that :)

Comment: @NarendraPathai you should not edit to fix syntax anyway :) (because that might be the issue sometimes)

Comment: @RC I wrote it wrong here..I am Sorry, will correct it..At that line itself I am getting Bound Mismatch..

Comment: What radiodef said: There is no System class in the FindService.class, or anywhere else in your question.